# Jquery Select label by ID

Tags: jquery, html, select, label

I have a label around 3 drop-down menus with an ID name but I am wondering how to select it with jquery. Here's my code: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jVHNd/)

How do I go about selecting the label by ID? thanks

Comment: Posting PHP code in a fiddle won't help (posting it here either, if the question is related to HTML/jQuery). The HTML code received by our browsers (the source code from a browser point of view) would be far more useful.

Answer (score 3):

You need the # to select by ID.

```
$("#ven_label").show();
```

Comment: I would even go with selector with only an id

Comment: And then you don't need the element. ID is unique by definition

Comment: "But adding label in front is faster since jQuery doesn't need to parse all the elements." --- this is just wrong

Comment: @zerkms, I'll look in to it but if I remember well, I got it off a Paul Irish video explaining jQuery. I'll try to find it.

Comment: @ComputerArts thank you very much, for some reason the intellisense wasn't picking this up but it works. Thanks

Comment: @ComputerArts: you're confusing it with something else

Comment: As of version 1.3, jQuery has been using the Sizzle Javascript Selector Library which uses a ‘right to left’ model rather than a ‘left to right’, which means that given a selector string such as $('div.class span.class2') the engine starts the search on the right using the most specific selector (the span.class2) and then checks each ancestor against div.class rather than starting on the left and checking descendants. Still, after running these tests, http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-speed-tests adding the element is slightly faster.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('label[id="ven_label"]').show();​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

or better

```
$('#ven_label').show();​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

But the problem in the example of "jsfiddle" is you were using "Mootools" instead of "jQuery":

[run example with jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/adescalzo/fbEe5/)

Answer (score 2):

you can [select by id](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) by simply type the `#id_name` in the `$()` like below

```
 $('#ven_label').show();
```

[here is the complete list of jquery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)